# Spring integration warning Referenced bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#0' not found"

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring-integration 4.0.0.M4 in my project, and in my spring-integration.xml, I use :

```
    <int:channel id="messages" >
    <int:queue />
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

    <int:service-activator id="myService"
    input-channel="messages" output-channel="nullChannel" ref="processor"
    method="processNotif">
    <int:poller task-executor="pool" fixed-rate="10" error-channel="errorChannel" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int:service-activator>
<task:executor id="pool" pool-size="5-25" queue-capacity="20" rejection-policy="DISCARD_OLDEST"
    keep-alive="120" />
```

I have warning:  " Referenced bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#0'  not found" and  "Referenced bean 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0' not found". Did that means that I miss something. 
It is just a warning but I would like to know how to fix this.

{Edited:}
[image]

Comment: Show, please, more logs. We need to know who complains with that WARN

Comment: I have added a screenshot

Comment: Forget it! It is an Eclipse issue, not runtime. :-) However 'Spring Nature' or STS might fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned issue has been fixed in the STS 3.7.0. See the JIRA [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3674) for more information.