# Referenced bean 'jpaMappingContext' not found

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I've recently run into some spring data rest problems which I haven't resolved yet. After closer examination I found out that xml warnings where switched off, and when I switched them on this two warnings where shown:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Referenced bean 'jpaMappingContext' not found [config set: test/test]
    - Class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator' is abstract [config set: test/
     test]
```

This is my spring-data-rest.xml, warnings are show at line `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.test"/>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.test"/> <!-- warnings on this line-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="postgreDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.model" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have searched for both warnings but with no luck. I'm guessing I either need to add some bean to config, or I'm missing some dependencies. Also I've searchd for jpaMappingContext bean, but found nothing of value.

My spring, hibernate, json and postgre dependencies are shwon below.

```
    <!-- PostgreSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- JSon -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring aspect oriented -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring HATEOAS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.16.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data rest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I resolve this warning?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945382/how-to-eliminate-bogus-referenced-bean-not-found-warnings-in-sts (assuming this is still somehow relevant to you)?

Comment: Do you actually have errors during runtime is it just in eclipse (assuming that is what you using) warnings?

Comment: I'm working on some other project right now, but I will check in few weeks once I'll be back on track with this one. Yes, Eclipse is in question.

Comment: Looks more like an Eclipse trash warnings. Could you please add the info about actual issues you have running the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. It's Eclipse or some Spring tooling rather than problem in your Spring context configuration. In my case it was Spring Tool Suite bug. I upgraded to version **3.7.0.RELEASE** which is built on **Eclipse Mars 4.5.1** and this warning disappered without any work.